# Flicker effect on hover transform

Tags: css, hover, transform

I'm trying to make a cube with 2 sides, one with an image container and the other with a text container. [Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/qVzwQK?p=preview) is the working plunker

I'm rotating the text container using:

```
.page__text {
  transform: rotateY(-90deg) translateZ(75px);
}
```

And on hover i'm rotating the Wrapper doing:

```
.wrapper:hover {
  transform: rotateY(90deg) translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
```

The hover works fine, but the problem is that when we move the mouse **without moving outside** the wrapper the transform makes a **flicker effect**, just like if we were leaving the element and the transformation were canceled

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

when the wrapper is rotated, it no longer has a good area on which you can do the hover (it is at 90 deg to your view)

change the hover state to the parent, that is still

```
.cube-page__item:hover .cube-page__item-wrapper {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(90deg) translate3d(0, 0, 0);
            transform: rotateY(90deg) translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
```

[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/HuhJ0iqFSK1GdiNahg7W?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks @vals i didn't notice that, now it works fine